# Text input and Focus in Adornment Layer (VSIX)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, adornment

I am making a Visual Studio IDE extension that has an Inline Difference View feature.

I used [`CreateDifferenceView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.differencing.iwpfdifferenceviewerfactoryservice.createdifferenceview?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) to create a [`FrameWorkElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement?view=windowsdesktop-8.0), be aware that this method will create two inner [`IWpfTextView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.iwpftextview?view=visualstudiosdk-2022). I then used [`AddAdornment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.iadornmentlayer.addadornment?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) to attach it to a [`IWpfTextView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.iwpftextview?view=visualstudiosdk-2022).

The problem is that the adornments don't receive keyboard focus properly. Initially, I can type into it, but the commands like <kbd>CTRL+A</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd>, etc... don't work, and they will be received/processed by the host [`IWpfTextView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.iwpftextview?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) instead of the adornments.

Learning from [this blog](https://joshvarty.com/2014/08/01/ripping-the-visual-studio-editor-apart-with-projection-buffers/), I have successfully got that working by using [`AddCommandFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivstextview.addcommandfilter?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) and pass the commands forward to the inner [`IVsTextView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivstextview?view=visualstudiosdk-2022)'s that was created by [`CreateDifferenceView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.differencing.iwpfdifferenceviewerfactoryservice.createdifferenceview?view=visualstudiosdk-2022).

Now the keyboard commands are working properly, but one problem remains, the adornments still aren't getting proper focus. You can see that although I can select the text in the adornment, the selection is still shown as "out-of-focus" grey, and the host [`IWpfTextView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.iwpftextview?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) doesn't lose its selection focus even when I clicked onto the adornments. Sorry that I had to attach a GIF, but there is no better way to describe the problem.:

[image]

---

What I had tried:

- Using [`FocusManager.SetIsFocusScope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.focusmanager.setisfocusscope?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) to set the scope.
- Calling [`UIElement.Focus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.focus?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) on the outer [`IWpfDifferenceViewer.VisualElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.differencing.iwpfdifferenceviewer.visualelement?view=visualstudiosdk-2022#microsoft-visualstudio-text-differencing-iwpfdifferenceviewer-visualelement) and the inner [`IWpfTextView.VisualElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.iwpftextview.visualelement?view=visualstudiosdk-2022)
- Calling [`SendExplicitFocus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivstextview.sendexplicitfocus?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) on the inner [`IVsTextView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivstextview?view=visualstudiosdk-2022)

The MRE (`MefProvider` just imports those components):

```cs
var docview = await VS.Documents.GetActiveDocumentViewAsync();
var contentType = docview.TextBuffer.ContentType;

var leftBuffer = MefProvider.TextBufferFactoryService.CreateTextBuffer("left content", contentType);
var rightBuffer = MefProvider.TextBufferFactoryService.CreateTextBuffer("right content", contentType);

var diffBuffer = MefProvider.DifferenceBufferFactory.CreateDifferenceBuffer(leftBuffer, rightBuffer);
var diffViewer = MefProvider.DifferenceViewerFactory.CreateDifferenceView(diffBuffer);

var adornmentLayer = docview.TextView.GetAdornmentLayer("MyAdornmentLayer");
adornmentLayer.AddAdornment(AdornmentPositioningBehavior.OwnerControlled, null, null, diffViewer.VisualElement, null);
```

Comment: any minimal reproduce example if possible?

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT the MRE is in the post, is it lacking? The post is already too long so I had to strip it down as much as possible. The only thing that is required is exporting "MyAdornmentLayer" but since that's common knowledge I didn't add it to the MRE.

Comment: I partially succeeded by using the [`ISpaceReservationManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.ispacereservationmanager?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) of the diff view to add an agent and fire the GotFocus event of it. But somehow after firing the event, the host view wanted to get the focus back and I couldn’t do anything about it. Eventually, I found a way to actually get this working by using an internal function: `AggregateFocusInterceptor.SetInterceptsAggregateFocus(hostView, true)` when the adornment view got focus.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround is to use an undocumented internal function in `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.dll`:

```cs
diffViewer.VisualElement.GotFocus += (o, e) => {
    AggregateFocusInterceptor.SetInterceptsAggregateFocus(hostView as DependencyObject, true);
};

diffViewer.VisualElement.LostFocus += (o, e) => {
    AggregateFocusInterceptor.SetInterceptsAggregateFocus(hostView as DependencyObject, false);
};
```

*You could take a look at the internal function `WpfTextView.QueueAggregateFocusCheck`* to see why this works.

Before trying this, I was getting a partially successful result by getting the [`ISpaceReservationManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.ispacereservationmanager?view=visualstudiosdk-2022%60) of the adornment text view then adding an agent to it and firing its [`GotFocus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.ispacereservationagent.gotfocus?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) event. This technically should work, however, right after the adornment text view got focus, the host view just steal the focus back. I suspect it might have something to do with the orders of the events being triggered.

I'm not accepting this as an answer because it's only a workaround and there should be a more correct way to do this.